# How to implement custom flaky test detection in Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops

Recent [Azure DevOps article about Flaky test management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/flaky-test-management?view=azure-devops) mentions custom detection of Flaky Tests, but I can't find any documentation about how to implement that.

I thought it might be part of [Publish test results task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-test-results) but I see no mention of Flaky Tests in there.

Comment: You can implement flaky test detection using azure devops rest api, by receiving test runs results you can determine if test is flaky and based on that fail or succeed task

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a missing of documents about how to implement custom flaky test detection.

I reported this issue to microsoft developer community. you can keep track on [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/722029/how-to-implement-custom-flaky-test-detection-in-az.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response Levi. I was asking about **Custom Detection** you've described the automatic detection. I'm not using VSTest, I have my own set of tooling for functional testing, that includes flaky test detection, and I post my test results using the Publish Test Results Task. I want to understand how I can make use of my own Flaky Test detection to inform Azure DevOps about them.

Comment: I just submitted a problem about this issue in developer community.

Comment: @IanSullivan but how is Azure's DevOps 'engine' supposed to know if the test is flaky or not? how to formalize flaky's affiliation of test for th subsequent declaration of this?

Comment: It’s been a while but I think idea was to call an API in AzureDevOps (ADO) to report the test results. See custom detection on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/flaky-test-management?view=azure-devops#flaky-test-detection